# Why vue need to forceUpdate components when they include static slot

Tags: vue.js

Why vue needs to forceUpdate child component that has a static slot when it update self

It will trigger too much update calculate when a component has lots of child components that has a static slot

```
// my-button.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>


// my-com.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <span>{{ foo }}</span>
    <template v-for="(item, index) in arr">
      <my-button>test</my-button>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      foo: 1,
      arr: (new Array(10000)).fill(1)
    }
  }
}
</scirpt>
```

If run `this.foo = 2` will lead update queue include 10000 watcher. When I read source code I found the following code

```
function updateChildComponent (
...

  // Any static slot children from the parent may have changed during parent's
  // update. Dynamic scoped slots may also have changed. In such cases, a forced
  // update is necessary to ensure correctness.
  const needsForceUpdate = !!(
    renderChildren ||               // has new static slots
    vm.$options._renderChildren ||  // has old static slots
    hasDynamicScopedSlot
  )

...


  // resolve slots + force update if has children
  if (needsForceUpdate) {
    vm.$slots = resolveSlots(renderChildren, parentVnode.context)
    vm.$forceUpdate()
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/9371) on GitHub.

> Unfortunately, any child components with static slot content still
>   need to be forced updated. This means the common use case of
>   `<parent><child></child></parent>` doesn't benefit from this change,
>   unless the default slot is explicitly forced into a scoped slot by
>   using `<parent v-slot:default><child></child></parent>`. (We cannot
>   directly force all slots into scoped slots as that would break
>   existing render function code that expects the slot to be present on
>   `this.$slots instead` of `this.$scopedSlots`)

Seems like it's fixed in `2.6`.

> In 2.6, we have introduced an optimization that further ensures parent
>   scope dependency mutations only affect the parent and would no longer
>   force the child component to update if it uses only scoped slots.

To solve your problem just update your Vue version to `2.6`. Since it's just a minor update nothing will break down. What about the reason to call `forceUpdate` - only **Evan You** knows that :)

Comment: Thanks! But this [pr](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/9371) is parts of `2.6`, so this problem doesn't fixed yet

Answer (score 0):

Hello i solved this problem with this:

```js
export function proxySlots(scopedSlots: any): any {
  return Object.keys(scopedSlots).reduce<any>(
    (acc, key) => {
      const fn = scopedSlots[key];
      fn.proxy = true;
      return { ...acc, [key]: fn };
    },
    { $stable: true },
  );
}
```

```js
const ctx = {
 // ...
 scopedSlots: proxySlots({ someSlot: () => <span>Hello</span>})
 // or from provided slots : this.$scopedSlots or context.slots if using composition api 
}
```

It's a bit hackish but no more forced update.